# Loading TF Records

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I had a COCO style annotations dataset I converted to TF Records following [this script](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_coco_tf_record.py), I was wondering how I could load these TF Record files in TensorFlow?

Comment: tf.Dataset I suppose - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset

Comment: @PermanentPon Well, of course but I was expecting a way to get the schema for COCO style dataset

Comment: Like this https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/creating_tfrecords/#define-tfrecords-helper-functions ?

Comment: or this - https://www.kaggle.com/karthikeyanvijayan/coco-object-detection-dataset-in-tfrecord?scriptVersionId=41324393&cellId=15 ?

Comment: Welcome. To avoid having your questing closed, All code, data, error messages, etc must be embedded in the question. It is fine to include external links as *supplemental*, but only if all relevant info pertaining to the problem is also embedded. Please *edit* to **include the code** in question, as well as **what you tried**. You can read more info on SO question requirements in the help section linked to at the top of every page.